# Tomcat webapp unable to create file in directory as permission denied

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets, centos

In my project, I created a servlet on which users can upload media files. These files will be saved based on a path in context param. In my home windows pc, it works well. However, on my linux vps, there is this permission denied error that appears on the localhost.log file.

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied
        at java.base/java.io.UnixFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:1024)
        at post.Upload.doPost(Upload.java:194)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
```

The file is supposed to be created and written to on /var/sociogram/media/public. I have tried

```
chown -R tomcat:tomcat /var/sociogram/media
```

and have read write permissions for the user when I do

```
ls -l /var/sociogram/media
```

web.xml: 
https://github.com/Manoharan-Ajay-Anand/sociogram/blob/master/Sociogram/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

servlet:
https://github.com/Manoharan-Ajay-Anand/sociogram/blob/master/Sociogram/src/main/java/post/Upload.java

Comment: Can you paste the log here?

Comment: @htopiwala I have pasted the log. This is the only thing I have. There is no exception printed to catalina.out

Answer (score 0):

> However, on my linux vps, there is this permission denied error that appears on the localhost.log file.

The file path mentioned in that error message -- does it exist?

Do you have "temp" directory in your $CATALINA_BASE directory? (Alongside with the usual "conf", "webapps", "logs" and "work" directories).

Answer (score 0):

The main problem was that my directories only had read write permissions. I realised that for unix systems x permission must be given for directories so that the program can transverse directory. Without it read,write permissions are useless.